# Calculate frequencie inter purchase : IMPALA

Tags: sql, date, impala

I have some difficulties to calculate the number of days between two dates.
This is my the code to create my table:

```
CREATE TABLE example_date (id_customer BIGINT,
                                id_product bigint, 
                                date_purchase STRING)

insert into example_date values (100,2,"19/04/2017") ; 
insert into example_date values(100,2,"22/06/2017");
insert into example_date values(100,2,"21/07/2017");
insert into example_date values(101,2,"23/04/2017");
insert into example_date values(102,2,"24/04/2017");
insert into example_date values(1000,3,"15/02/2017");
insert into example_date values(1000,3,"23/02/2017");
insert into example_date values(1000,3,"29/04/2017");
insert into example_date values(1000,3,"06/05/2017");
insert into example_date values(1001,3,"10/08/2017");
```

For each id_customer and for each id_product, I would like to calculate the number of days between each date.

I have used the lag function, but I don't obtain the good results.
This is my query:

```
Select *, LAG (cast (dt_ticket_sale as timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id_customer, id_product ORDER BY id_customer DESC, id_product desc) AS test
from example_date;
```

Comment: Insufficient parentheses on the LAG function

Comment: Select *, LAG (cast (dt_ticket_sale as timestamp)) OVER (PARTITION BY id_customer, id_product ORDER BY id_customer DESC, id_product desc) AS test
from example_date;